# Short any value in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I'm quite a beginner in programming, and I want to make it shorter: code:

For y as integer = 1 to 5

```
'Code'
```

Next

```
Using sw As New StreamWriter(filepath)
        sw.WriteLine("[TxtStringNumP1]")
        sw.WriteLine(TxtStringNumP1.Text)
        sw.WriteLine("[TxtStringNumP2]")
        sw.WriteLine(TxtStringNumP2.Text)
        sw.WriteLine("[TxtStringNumP3]")
        sw.WriteLine(TxtStringNumP3.Text)
        sw.WriteLine("[TxtStringNumP4]")
        sw.WriteLine(TxtStringNumP4.Text)
        sw.WriteLine("[TxtStringNumP5]")
        sw.WriteLine(TxtStringNumP5.Text)
End Using
MsgBox("Ok", vbInformation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this bit shorter:

```
For y as integer = 1 to 5

For y = 1 to 5
```

And you can then rely on the fact that your control have names that differ only by a number, and there is some collection of them that knows them by name:

```
    For y = 1 To 5
        Dim n = "TxtStringNumP" & y          'formulate the name
        Dim c = Me.Controls.Find(n, True)    'find all controls with a matcing name, returns a collection of controls
        sw.WriteLine($"[{n}]")               'write the name we formulated
        sw.WriteLine(c(0).Text)              'write the text of the first control. All controls have a Text property, we don't need to convert it to textbox
    Next
```